# how to draw rectangle on a image dynamically using canvas in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Line, SteppedLine, PolyLine, Circle, Rectangle} from 'draw-shape-reactjs';
import img from '../images/mountains1.jpg'
import './parentContainerCSS.css'

class ParentContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      point1: [0, 0],
      point2: [0, 0],
      widthRect: 0,
      heightRect: 0
    }

    this.init = this.init.bind(this)
    this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind(this)
    this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this)
    this.mouseMove = this.mouseMove.bind(this)
    this.draw = this.draw.bind(this)
    this.drawImage = this.drawImage.bind(this)


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    this.rect = {}
    this.canvasX = this.canvas.offsetLeft
    this.canvasY = this.canvas.offsetTop
    this.drag = false

    this.init()
  }

  drawImage = () => {
    console.log('im in drawImage')
    this.backgroundImage = new Image()

    this.backgroundImage.src = {
      img
    }

    this.backgroundImage.onload = function() {
      console.log('backgroundImage is loaded')
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.backgroundImage, 0, 0)
    }
  }

  init = () => {
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown, false)
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp, false)
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove, false)
  }

  mouseDown = (e) => {

    this.rect.x = e.pageX - this.canvasX + 0
    this.rect.y = e.pageY - this.canvasY + 0
    this.rect.w = 0
    this.rect.h = 0
    this.setState({
      point1: [this.rect.x, this.rect.y],
      point2: [0, 0],
      widthRect: 0,
      heightRect: 0
    })
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
    this.drag = true
  }

  mouseUp = () => {
    this.drag = false
  }

  mouseMove = (e) => {

    if (this.drag) {
      this.rect.w = (e.pageX - this.canvasX) - this.rect.x
      this.rect.h = (e.pageY - this.canvasY) - this.rect.y
      this.setState({
        point2: [this.rect.x + this.rect.w, this.rect.y + this.rect.h],
        point1: [this.rect.x, this.rect.y],
        widthRect: Math.abs(this.rect.w),
        heightRect: Math.abs(this.rect.h)
      })
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
      this.draw()
    }
  }

  draw = () => {
    this.ctx.setLineDash([2])

    this.ctx.strokeRect(this.rect.x, this.rect.y, this.rect.w, this.rect.h)
  }

  render() {


    return ( <
      div >

      <
      canvas id = "canvas"
      width = "800"
      height = "450"
      src = {
        img
      } > < /canvas>

      <
      button onClick = {
        this.drawImage
      } > Draw Image < /button> <
      p > < strong > (X1, Y1): < /strong> ({this.state.point1[0]}, {this.state.point1[1]})</p >
      <
      p > < strong > (X2, Y2): < /strong> ({this.state.point2[0]}, {this.state.point2[1]})</p >
      <
      p > < strong > Size: < /strong> ({this.state.widthRect}X{this.state.heightRect})</p >
      <
      p id = 'demo' > < /p>

      <
      /div>
    )
  }
}

export default ParentContainer
```

currently im having a white canvas as output on which i can draw rectangle by dragging mouse but i want to do so on a image instead of white canvas
i'm also having problem with my backgroundImage.onload event which is not working or background image is not loading 
is there any other way of doing this or the current code can be improved??

Comment: Did you fix this? Can you share the code?

Comment: i did set image as background-image for canvas to draw on it and resized the canvas according to image width and height

Comment: code is available on my git https://github.com/devspartan/reactJS/blob/master/ParentContainer.js                                         hope you can make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your are clearing the image that is loaded in canvas, remove the code below from the `mouseDown` method and give it a try.

```js
this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
```